# Access Form VBA: double record when saving

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access Form, I have a `Save` button whose aim is to add the new record to the `table` called `Data Processing List`.

The problem is that pushing the button, the record entered is saved into the table twice. I mean, two identical records.

I can't understand why, because the code is really simple:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
On Error GoTo Save_Click_Err

    Me.Today.SetFocus

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data Processing List")
        .AddNew
        !Department = Me.Department.Value
        .Update
    End With

Save_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Save_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Save_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

This is an example when I try to save the record with the word "prova".
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are saving twice:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand **acCmdSaveRecord**
...
With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data Processing List")
    .AddNew
    !Department = Me.Department.Value
    .**Update**
End With
```